# SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [Date] = ([Date] + 8 hours)

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

My problem starts with the fact that my server is in a totally different country, so we have a difference of 8 hours (GMT).

So when I'm trying to do something like this:

```
CreateNewDataSet("SELECT * FROM tblArchives WHERE [Date] =" & DateAndTime.Today.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "'; & , "tblArchives")
```

It won't get all the results because it happened today in my country but yesterday where the server is based.

I tried unsuccessfully to use the `DATEADD` function.

Is there any way to do something like:

```
SELECT FROM WHERE [DATE+8 hours] =DateAndTime.Today.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: please show us how did you use DateAdd function ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you subtract the hours from the other side of the condition statement:

```
CreateNewDataSet("SELECT * FROM tblArchives WHERE [Date] =" & DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, -8, DateAndTime.Today.Date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "'; & , "tblArchives")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move the date calculation in to the SQL so that you get the servers date something like

```
SELECT * FROM tblArchives WHERE Date = DateAdd(HH, +8,getdate())
```

try to run `DateAdd(HH, +8,getdate())` to see the actual date and time it uses in your query. I have similar needs but I always set the time to be 1 millisecond after midnight to one millisecond before midnight. This will make sure you get all the data for a particular day.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use [DateTime.AddHours](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method

```
"SELECT * FROM tblArchives WHERE [Date] =" & 
DateAndTime.Today.AddHours(-8).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

*Instead of adding `+8` hours to `[Date]` Column, add `-8` to the current server date*

Comment: THank you all guys, i'll try your solutions!

Comment: @ILavi still waiting for ur reply

Comment: @ILavi if an answer solved ur issue you have to [accept it](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) or give a feedback to get more helped